# SubPub pattern with type parameters

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to plan a publish/subscribe implementation. I've tried several times but I get stuck cause I think either I don't understand the limitations of C# generics or I haven't gotten the correct way to do it.

I would like to keep a list of Events/Delegates that are associated with a type of object. So when the Method gets called it receives an object of correct type.

Furthermore I would like the way to use it to be like this:

```cs
Hub.Subscribe<MyMessageType>( MethodThatTakes<MyMessageType>);
Hub.Publish<MyMessageType>( new MyMessageType("Message"));

Hub.Subscribe<Vector3>( MethodThatTakes<Vector3>);
Hub.Publish<Vector3>( new Vector3(45,100,0));
```

My problem is I don't manage to get it to work this way. It becomes more complex to use but I'm thinking that the user shouldn't need to do more since more information is not needed.

So my question is if it's possible to make it work like this with generics or maybe I misunderstand something about how a pub sub could and should work?

Example of code to register a subscription

```cs
public static void Subscribe < T > (string title = "", CallbackMethod<T>) {
   Subscriptions subs;

   if (subscriptions.Any(sub => sub.Type == typeof (T) && sub.Title == title)) {
     subs = subscriptions.First(sub => sub.Type == typeof (T) && sub.Title == title);
   } else {
     subs = new Subscriptions < T > (title);
   }
}

class Subscriptions < T > {
   internal Type Type;
   List < CallbackMethodsWithParameter < T >> subscribers;

   public Subscriptions() {
     Type = T.GetType();
   }
}
```

So here I am trying to have a subscriptions class store type of return and a list with methods to callback that takes an object of the same type.

It obviously doesn't work but that's where I am now and I'm not sure if it's even possible or a good way to do it.

Comment: In `Subscribe<T>` what are you doing with `subs` variable? Nothing it seems. And where is subscriptions` declared?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want to do, but it would appear you want to keep a `Dictionary<(Type, string), object>` in `Hub`, store the instances of `Subscriptions<T>` in there as `object`s, look them up by the tuple of Type + title, and cast the looked up instance to `Subscriptions<T>` before use.

Comment: @Charlieface sorry you are right. subscriptions is a dictionary declared earlier. Subs is used to store subscriptions. It's not really code. In just trying to explain what I try to achieve.

Comment: @GSerg i think you understood it and i think that did the trick! The missing piece was that i should store it as objects and then cast it when it to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample registration code seems overly complex for what you are trying to achieve, which is simply registering an `Action<T>` and then publishing a message of `T` to all subscriptions.

However, this is not easily mapped for your use case since `Action<in T>` is contravariant and you need to store your handlers as `Action<object>` which would be a covariant interaction.  That said, you can wrap the subscription handler and cast the incoming message.

```
public class Hub
{
    private static object _subscriptionLock = new object();
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<Type, ConcurrentBag<Action<object>>> _map = 
        new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, ConcurrentBag<Action<object>>>();

    public void Subscribe<T>(Action<T> subscriptionHandler)
    {
        var entryExists = _map.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var entry);
        var wrappedHandler = Wrap(subscriptionHandler);

        if (!entryExists)
        {
            entry = new ConcurrentBag<Action<object>>();
        }

        entry.Add(wrappedHandler);
        _map[typeof(T)] = entry;
    }
    
    public void Publish<T>(T message)
    {
        var entryExists = _map.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var entry);
        
        if (!entryExists) return;
        
        foreach (var handler in entry)
        {
            handler(message);
        }
    }
    
    private Action<object> Wrap<T>(Action<T> input)
    {
        Action<object> f = (message) => input((T)message);
        return f;
    }
}
```

This allows the type of subscription and publish API that you are looking for:

```
void Main()
{
    var hub = new Hub();
    
    hub.Subscribe<TestMessageA>(HandlerOne);
    hub.Subscribe<TestMessageA>(HandlerTwo);
    hub.Subscribe<TestMessageB>(HandlerOne);
    hub.Subscribe<TestMessageB>(HandlerTwo);
    
    hub.Publish(new TestMessageA { Title = "hey there!" });
    hub.Publish(new TestMessageB { Title = "hey there again!" });
}

public void HandlerOne(TestMessageA message)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{message.Title} in HandlerOne");
}

public void HandlerTwo(TestMessageA message)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{message.Title} in HandlerTwo");
}

public void HandlerOne(TestMessageB message)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{message.Title} in HandlerOne");
}

public void HandlerTwo(TestMessageB message)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{message.Title} in HandlerTwo");
}

public class TestMessageA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class TestMessageB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

which outputs:

```
hey there! in HandlerOne
hey there! in HandlerTwo
hey there again! in HandlerOne
hey there again! in HandlerTwo
```